# Schedulling for Cloud Dataflow Job

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow

So, I already finish to create a job in Dataflow. This job to process ETL from PostgreSQL to BigQuery. So, I don't know to create a schedulling using Airflow. Can share how to schedule job dataflow using Airflow?

Thank you

Comment: Any specific reason to use Airflow? [Dataflow Data Pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/data-pipelines) has scheduling features.

Comment: what is schedulling feature of dataflow data pipelines? is additional cost if use that features?

Comment: The link above explains how to import a job (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/data-pipelines#import_a_job). I don't think there's additional cost (besides the Dataflow usage driven by it), as the feature doesn't mention any pricing.

Comment: Hmm. So create a job scheduler in Dataflow in Google Cloud Console. and I don't need to save Dataflow in Cloud Storage, right? because I want to save dataflow job in Cloud storage, then Airflow will schedule job in Cloud Storage?

Comment: Dataflow Data Pipelines is an alternative to Airflow. I don't see a reason to keep both if you decide to use Data Pipelines from the console (at least on the scheduling part). By "Save Dataflow job to Cloud Storage" are you referring to Dataflow Templates?

Comment: I see. So if I using dataflow data pipeline to perform ETL/ELT and I can schedule job because dataflow scheduling features, I don't need install airflow, is it right? And "Save dataflow job to cloud storage", yes I will using Dataflow with python language, so Do I need to save dataflow job to cloud storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule dataflow batch jobs using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)  (fully managed cron job scheduler) / [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) (fully managed workflow orchestration service built on Apache Airflow).

To schedule using Cloud Scheduler refer [Schedule Dataflow batch jobs with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/schedule-dataflow-jobs-with-cloud-scheduler)

To schedule using Cloud Composer refer [Launching Dataflow pipelines with Cloud Composer using DataflowTemplateOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator).

For examples and more ways to run Dataflow jobs in Airflow using Java/Python SDKs refer [Google Cloud Dataflow Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html#google-cloud-dataflow-operators)

Comment: I see.
But if using cloud scheduler or cloud composer, is additional cost to using schedulling features?

Comment: Yes, $0.10 per job per month & 3 free jobs per month, per billing account. Refer the cloud scheduling pricing here https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing

Comment: Welcome, if it satisfies your requirement, accept the answer. Thank!

Comment: I want to ask a question. If I have SSH terminal in compute engine, Is possible to create cron job in SSH Terminal compute engine with no additional cost? Thank you

Comment: Refer here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions

Answer (score 1):

In your `Airflow` DAG, you can define a `cron` and a scheduling with `schedule_interval` param  :

```py
with airflow.DAG(
        my_dag,
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval="5 3 * * *"

    # Trigger Dataflow job with an operator
    launch_dataflow_job = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
        runner='DataflowRunner',
        py_file=python_main_file,
        task_id='launch_dataflow_job',
        pipeline_options=dataflow_job_options,
        py_system_site_packages=False,
        py_interpreter='python3',
        dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
            location='region'
        )
    )

    launch_dataflow_job
    ......
```

Comment: I see
Is this script separated of my ETL script?
Is need to install airflow?

Comment: I don’t understand the question, you mentioned Airflow, I assumed Airflow was already installed. The code I shared is a Airflow DAG

Comment: If using Airflow, is there additional cost if using airflow?

Comment: Are you using Cloud Composer in Google Cloud ?

Comment: No. I have plan to use cloud dataflow as process ETL Job to load to BigQuery. I want to schedule ETL Job with no additional cost. If I open SSH terminal from compute engine and then create a dataflow job and then create a cron job, can I create a cron job to running ETL job in SSH terminal from compute engine?